# Is a machine used primarily as a professional workstation considered "professional capacity"?

Tags: support

EDIT:  I deleted the original and moved [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/833457/how-to-enabled-hardware-based-encryption-on-samsung-850-pro) to SuperUser.

I'm new to serverfault, I've asked [one question](https://serverfault.com/questions/640648/how-to-enable-hardware-based-encryption-with-samsung-850-pro) and it's been downvoted with no comment.  Do you think that's because someone decided that a hard drive in my professional workstation which needs to be encrypted because of my employers rules is not within a "professional capacity"?  If so, can you please direct me to more on-topic stackexchange site?  Otherwise, suggestions on how to improve my question are welcome.

Comment: It's not a very good question, either.  Even if you are using this computer for professional purposes, ~"halp, how do I encrypt my computer.. and by the way, what's TPM?" is a bad question that doesn't meet the site's quality standards... though you can be excused for not noticing that for all the other crap questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ServerFault is better suited for questions related to the things system administrators encounter on a day-to-day basis. Regardless of its use-type, a workstation "question" is off-topic here. It would be on-topic if you were to say ask a question about deploying machines with encrypted drives or the best practices to that effect.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense and it sounds like SuperUser would have been a better starting point.

Answer (score 6):

Your original question said nothing about a professional workstation, and still says nothing about your employer requiring encryption at rest.

Readers of any question can only judge it by what is *present* in the question, not what is left unsaid. As originally written it looks like a question about *personal* use, which is off-topic here.

Comment: That make's a lot of sense, I believe it is on-topic but instead of debating about it I'll ask to have it moved once I figure out where it might be better received

Comment: What's to debate? You can always edit your question.

Comment: @ErlVolton It's not a question that's nearly good enough to be moved either, to be honest, and that's even ignoring the obvious "call Samsung support and ask them" answer.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I dunno, I'd personally like to know more about these drives, if only so I can evaluate whether they're secure _enough_ and how on earth I'm supposed to manage them.

Comment: @HopelessN00b You already did a really good job of letting me know you think my question is low quality.  I've seen the responses other people have gotten from Samsung and they are complete unsatisfactory so I have no intention of wasting my time there.  Surely there is a site with people who have experience using the encryption on these drives where "Halp how do I encrypt my drive and whats TPM" will be on topic.

Comment: @ErlVolton "What's TPM?" is a question answerable by a bit of search engine prowling (it's a physical chip on the motherboard, by the way). Drive encryption is the same ...you just have to look.

Comment: @NathanC Yes so I understand that TPM is a chip relating to hardware-based encryption the question was "Is TPM the thing I need?" which I have now simplified to "what is the feature I need?" so as not to confuse people  by making the question about TPM somehow.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Serverfault is a place for questions related to professional system administration. That is a question specific to your employer, or, at the very liberal, SuperUser.com, though I suspect they'll punt it as well.

Comment: I think SuperUser would be a really good fit, can you explain why they may punt it and where you would ask the question if it was yours?

Comment: @ErlVolton SU might well send it _here_, bringing you full circle. It would be best to improve the question as much as possible, before trying to take it elsewhere.